# including monitor thresholds in datadog monitors for terraform 0.13

Tags: terraform, datadog, terraform0.12+

I currently am using terraform version 0.13.0 and I have a set of resources of type `datadog_monitor`.

Within these resources, I have defined `monitor_thresholds` but when I try to init and plan, i get an error saying `An argument named "monitor_thresholds" is not expected here. Did you mean to define a block of type "monitor_thresholds".`

I do not understand why monitor_thresholds isn't recognised, since it's given as part of [the documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/DataDog/datadog/latest/docs/resources/monitor) - would anyone know of a possible cause?

Comment: Can you share your `datadog_monitor` block? Also, check in case you typed `monitor_thresholds = {` - try dropping the `=` since that would signify an argument rather than a block.

Comment: the issue was they had =, thanks :)